# SQL Dynamic Query Insertion with SQL user which has execute permission on stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a user in sql database which has execute permission on the stored procedure. On Store Procedure i am trying to insert into the table by : EXEC (@insertQuery) 
But i get following error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT permission was denied on the object ''table_name'', database ''db name'', schema ''dbo''.Unexpected error occurred!
```

I have looked into **EXECUTE AS Clause** also this will work , Is there any method beside this ? Safe one .

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `WITH EXECUTE AS` clause when you create the stored procedure.  You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql#syntax).

You can define the stored procedure to execute as the `OWNER` of the stored procedure.  This is very, very handy.  You can prevent users from directly modifying tables.  But, you can give them access to stored procedures that can modify the tables.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `EXECUTE AS` is with module signing. This requires more configuration than `EXECUTE AS` but has the advantage of retaining the callers identity without granting direct permissions to the user and can be extended for cross-database access.

Below is an example script gleaned from Erland Sommarskog's excellent and thorough article on [Giving Permissions through Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.testtbl (a int NOT NULL,
                      b int NOT NULL);
INSERT dbo.testtbl (a, b) VALUES (47, 11);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE example_sp AS
   SELECT SYSTEM_USER, USER, name, type, usage FROM sys.user_token;
   EXEC ('SELECT a, b FROM testtbl');
GO
-- Create the certificate.
CREATE CERTIFICATE examplecert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'All you need is love'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificate for example_sp',
   START_DATE = '20020101', EXPIRY_DATE = '20200101';
GO
-- Create the certificate user and give it rights to access the test table.
CREATE USER examplecertuser FROM CERTIFICATE examplecert;
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.testtbl TO examplecertuser;
GO
-- Sign the procedure.
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.example_sp BY CERTIFICATE examplecert
    WITH PASSWORD = 'All you need is love';
GO

--users need proc execute permissions but not table permissions
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.example_sp TO YourUserOrRole;
GO
```

Comment: I have the proc which has execute permission . Inside the proc there is insert query and other many query. 
Other query works well , but when i try to run dynamic query (insert one):  By : exec  (@insertQuery)  ... i get error